# como puedo obtener un valor numerico desde un formulario <input type="number">

Tags: javascript, html

hola amigos tengo una pregunta sobre un valor que no he podido solucionar... tengo en mi html un formulario en el cual quiero tomar dos valores desde un (input type="number") y después operarlos para realizar diferentes ejercicios (independientemente de esto)...

```
        <form action="" id="formulario">
        <div class="bloque1">
            <label for="numero1">ingrese el primer numero</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="numero1"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="bloque2">
            <label for="numero2">ingrese el segundo numero</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="numero2">
        </div>
    </form>
```

al tomar los valores de este formulario con:
(antes inicializo "let num1 = 0 | let num2= 0 )

```
    num1 = document.getElementById("numero1").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("numero2").value;
```

... en teoria deberia obtener en cada variable un numero, o no?... bueno, al intentar operar num1 + num 2
resulta que los concatena y no los opera, por ende hago la prueba con:

```
console.log(typeof num1);
console.log(typeof num2);
```

... y dicen que son tipo string
enseguida utilizo:

```
parseInt(num1, 10);
parseInt(num2, 10);
```

... inmediatamente antes de los console.log y me vuelve a decir que son tipo string... alguna sugerencia de que puedo hacer para convertir este para de variables a numeros **ENTEROS**???

Comment: No los estás convirtiendo, necesitas asignarlos: `num1 = parseInt(num1);`

Comment: totalmente de acuerdo, ya me di cuenta (que tonto) jejeje

Comment: ahota tengo otra duda, en ese mismo input... como hago para imprimir un numero grande... me explico: cuando pongo un numero de mas de 23 cifras el interprestador me lo toma como "ese_numero e+24" y pues yo lo necesito el numero como tal sin el exponente

Comment: para números grandes probá el tipo bigInt https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt

Answer (score 2):

Si el input es tipo numerico, puedes tomar el valor numerico con *valueAsNumber*:

```
number1 = document.getElementById("numero1").valueAsNumber
```

Esta propiedad nos permite evitar `parseInt/ parseFloat`.

**Nota:** *valueAsNumbers* devuelve **NaN** si el input está vacío.